# How to set two columns in many to many table as primary keys?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have a many to many table, i`m trying to have the two join columns as primary keys , without using a generated one. i`m using a typeorm with version>0.3, so using {prime:true} does not work.
[image]

i tried doing whats commented, didnt work.

Comment: *two join columns as primary keys* Do you mean the composite primary key?

Comment: Did you find a pertinent way? I'm struggling to find a solution too....

Answer (score -1):

The table with the composite primary key (type, code)

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryColumn,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Client } from './client.entity';

@Entity('classifier')
export class Classifier {
  @PrimaryColumn({ comment: 'Classifier Code' })
  code: number;

  @PrimaryColumn({ comment: 'Classifier Type', name: 'type' })
  type: number;

  @Column({ comment: 'Classifier Value 1' })
  lex1: string;

  @Column({ comment: 'Classifier Value 2', nullable: true })
  lex2: string;

  @Column({ comment: 'Classifier Value 3', nullable: true })
  lex3: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Client, (client) => client.client_type)
  clients: Client[];
}
```

The table with the composite foreign key (t_client_type, c_client_type)

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Classifier } from './classifier.entity';

@Entity('clients')
export class Client {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ comment: 'Client ID', name: 'client_id' })
  id: number;

  @Column({ comment: 'Client type classifier type', default: 1 })
  t_client_type: number;

  @Column({ comment: 'Client type classifier code', default: 2 })
  c_client_type: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Classifier, (classifier) => classifier.clients)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 't_client_type', referencedColumnName: 'type' },
    { name: 'c_client_type', referencedColumnName: 'code' },
  ])
  client_type: Classifier;

  @Column({
    comment: 'Client name',
    nullable: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: I just tried your snippet and it doesn't work. I got the error: ```QueryFailedError: ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE: Can't create table `oryzen2`.`clients` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```